# Pytorch "Unfold" equivalent in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch

Say I have grayscale images of size (50*50), with a batch size of 2 in this case, and i use the Pytorch Unfold function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from torch import nn
from torch import tensor

image1 = np.random.rand(1,50,50)
image2 = np.random.rand(1,50,50)
image = np.stack((image1,image2))
image = tensor(image)

ds = nn.Unfold(kernel_size=(2,2),stride=2)
x = ds(image).numpy()
x.shape

## OUTPUT: (2, 4, 625)
```

What would be the equivalent tensorflow implementation so that the output of the tensorflow implementation would exactly match 'x'? I've tried using the tf.image.extract_patches function but it seems to not be giving me what I quite want.

The question is then: What is the tensorflow implementation of Unfold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tf.image.extract_patches()`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tf-extract-image-patches-in-pytorch/43837/4) is analogous to `torch.nn.Unfold`, but you need to rejig the parameters slightly:

```py
tf.image.extract_patches(image, sizes=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], rates=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
```

Comment: I see there is also [`tf.image.extract_glimpses()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/extract_glimpse). Are you aware of an inverse method(s) for these? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using this yielded the same results exactly and Pytorch's Unfold

```
testimage = np.rollaxis(image,1,4)
z = tf.image.extract_patches(testimage, sizes=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], rates=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
z = np.reshape(z, (2,625,4))
```